# Использование z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, z-index

На страничке есть элемент `div` (назовём его `div1`) класса `work` у которого `z-index=1`, а в этом элементе есть элемент `div`(назовём его `div2`) класса `center` у которого `z-index=3`.

Я с помощью JavaScript создаю элемент `div`(назовём его `div3`) класса `block` у которого `z-index=2`.
Как я понимаю в таком случае, та часть `div3`, которая пересекается с `div2` должна быть не видна(т.к. у `div2` `z-index` больше), но на деле получается не так, и элемент `div3` оказывается выше `div2` и `div1`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

Код страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function gen(){
            var nDiv = document.createElement("div");
            var div2 = document.getElementById("mb");
            nDiv.setAttribute("class", "block");
            div2.appendChild(nDiv);

            }
    </script>

    <style>
        html{
            background-color: #FFF;
            width:1280px; 
            height:720px; 
            margin:0; 
            padding:0;
        }
        body{
            position:relative;
            width:1280px; 
            height:720px; 
            margin:0; 
            padding:0;
            background-color: #eeeae0;
            background-image:url(img/main.png); 
            z-index:1;  
            }
        .work{
            position:relative;
            background-color:#F32;
            width:1216px;
            height:666px;
            left:32px;
            top:32px;
            z-index:1;      
        }
        .center{
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            width: 1200px;  
            text-align:center;
            position:relative;
            z-index: 3; 
            height:500px;
            background-color:#23F;
        }
        .block {
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
            left:20px;
            top:100px;
            position:absolute;
            margin:0 auto; 
            z-index:2;
            background-color:#966;
            }
    </style>



    <title>Вход</title>
</head>

<body id="mb" onload="gen();">
        <div class="work" >
            <div class="center" ></div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: у элемента должен быть position: relative; иначе z-index не будет работать

Comment: @Валентин Жуков , у меня там (если я конечно, нигде не ошибся) везде стоит либо relative, либо absolute....

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt, вам сюда [MDN. The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)